An example of a commutative ring which is not SIP
Recall that a module $M_R$ ($R$ is a unital ring) is called an SIP-module if the intersection of any two summands of $M$ is a summand. The ring $R$ is called (left) right SIP-ring if the module (${}_RR$) $R_R$ is an SIP-module.
Is there a commutative ring (with unity) which is NOT an SIP-ring?

One can prove quite elementarily that for central idempotents $e, f$, we have $eR\cap fR=efR$.  Since summands are precisely of that form, that settles things.

Thanks. This is a good answer. But excuse me, I want to ask is every $R$-submodule of a commutative ring $R$ is an SIP-module? (i.e., is every ideal of $R$ is also an SIP-module?)

Do  I  understand  the  definition of  SIP correctly?: If  $N_1$ and  $N_2$ are  complemented  submodules of  M  then their intersection is  a  complemented submodule  again

The answer is no. If $R$ is commutative with unity and $S$ and $S'$ are summands of $R$ as an $R$-module then there are associated idempotent decompositions of the identity $1=e_1+e_2$ and $1=e'_1+e'_2$. So $S=e_1R$ and $S'=e'_1R$. Then multiplying, we get $1=e_1e'_1+e_1e'_2+e_2e'_1+e_2e'_2$. The idempotent $e_1e'_1$ projects onto $S\cap S'= SS'$, with complement $(e_1e'_2+e_2e'_1+e_2e'_2)R$.
